# Brightness on digital output varies based on level input type

Tags: arduino

Basically, I am following the tutorial code in *[BarGraph](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BarGraph)* for the LED bar graph. I do not have a potentiometer, so I thought to mimic it by using a [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) serial write, based on the dimmer example in *[Dimmer](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Dimmer)*. I have set the `sensorReading` value to the input from the Processing application (updating its grid to be 1023 elements) like so:

```
  int sensorReading;
  if (Serial.available()) {
      // Read the most recent byte (which will be from 0 to 1023):
      sensorReading = Serial.read();
  }
```

This does light up the LEDs based on my mouse position in the grid in the Processing application. However the LEDs are very dim. If I change how I set the `sensorReading` value to:

```
  int sensorReading = random(0, 1023);
```

Then the LEDs light up much brighter. Since the LEDs are all on the digital out pins I thought it would just send on/off based on the `sensorReading` value and would not have anything to do with how bright. What am I missing?

Here is the Processing code:

```
 // Dimmer - sends bytes over a serial port
 // by David A. Mellis
 //
 // This example code is in the public domain.

 import processing.serial.*;
 Serial port;

 void setup() {
     size(256, 150);

     println("Available serial ports:");
     println(Serial.list());

     // Uses the first port in this list (number 0). Change this to
     // select the port corresponding to your Arduino board. The last
     // parameter (for example, 9600) is the speed of the communication. It
     // has to correspond to the value passed to Serial.begin() in your
     // Arduino sketch.
     //port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);

     // If you know the name of the port used by the Arduino board, you
     // can specify it directly like this.
     port = new Serial(this, "COM6", 9600);
 }

 void draw() {
     // Draw a gradient from black to white
     for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
         stroke(i);
         line(i, 0, i, 150);
     }

     // Write the current X-position of the mouse to the serial port as
     // a single byte.
     port.write(mouseX);
 }
```

Here is the Arduino code:

```
// These constants won't change:
const int analogPin = A0;   // The pin that the potentiometer is attached to.
const int ledCount = 10;    // The number of LEDs in the bar graph.

int ledPins[] = {
  2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8,9,10,11 };   // An array of pin numbers to which LEDs are attached.

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    // Loop over the pin array and set them all to output:
    for (int thisLed = 0; thisLed < ledCount; thisLed++) {
      pinMode(ledPins[thisLed], OUTPUT);
    }
}

void loop() {
    // Read the potentiometer:
    //   int sensorReading = random(0, 1023);
    //   delay(250);
    byte streamReading;
    if (Serial.available()) {
        // Read the most recent byte (which will be from 0 to 255):
        sensorReading = Serial.read();
    }
    //Serial.println(sensorReading);

    // Map the result to a range from 0 to the number of LEDs:
    int ledLevel = map(sensorReading, 0, 255, 0, ledCount);

    // Loop over the LED array:
    for (int thisLed = 0; thisLed < ledCount; thisLed++) {
        // If the array element's index is less than ledLevel,
        // turn the pin for this element on:
        if (thisLed < ledLevel) {
            digitalWrite(ledPins[thisLed], HIGH);
        }
        // Turn off all pins higher than the ledLevel:
        else {
            digitalWrite(ledPins[thisLed], LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste in the code you use to set the output pins?  In fact, seeing the rest of your `loop()` would be useful too... I have a theory :)

Comment: @angelatlarge, the full code is at those 2 links. The code I am replacing is the readAnalog as I do not have a pot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** Your processing code is [sending data constantly](http://processing.org/reference/draw_.html), sending serial data to your Arduino *all the time*:

> Called directly after setup(), the draw() function continuously
>   executes the lines of code contained inside its block until the
>   program is stopped or noLoop() is called. draw() is called
>   automatically and should never be called explicitly.

This causes your Arduino sketch to update the LED on/off status frequently, and given how you read the data, this will result in LEDs pulsing really fast.

**Solution:** The simplest fix would be to add a delay to either the Arduino or the Processing sketch. An even better solution would be to modify the Processing code to only send data when the value changes; although note that since mouse values change almost constantly and that those changes wouldn't be significant for the Arduino code, you still might have a lot of unnecessary flickering. However, if you fix the serial read function in your Arduino code, the flickering will not be as much of a problem anyway.)

**Code:** Modify your Processing code to track the last reading, and only update if it is different:

```
int lastMouseX; 

void draw() {
 // draw a gradient from black to white ...

 int newMouseX = mouseX;
 if (newMouseX != lastMouseX) {
    lastMouseX = newMouseX
    // write the current X-position of the mouse to the serial port as
    // a single byte
    port.write(mouseX);
 }
```

---

**Other issues:** First of all there is an issue if you are expecting a value 0-1024: the Arduino's [analogWrite()](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/analogWrite) function takes a byte 0-255.

Secondly, as [Martin Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106092/martin-thompson) points out, you are probably sending a string such as `128` from your processing application, and then using its ASCII values to set the intensity. Since ASCII values of `0` through `9` are in the 48-57 range, that will give you a relatively low intensity. Note that when a string of more than one byte somes in (such as `128`) you are using only only one byte for intensity. So you have two options:

- Send a real binary byte, not a string. This is what is done in the dimmer example you show
- Send a string, and then convert it to its binary representation. For this you will need to read all the characters up until some delimiter (such as CR, or space), collect them up, and then convert.

This code might look something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int idxChar = 0;
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10
char strIntensity[BUFFER_SIZE];


...

while (Serial.available()) {
    // read the string representation of a byte
    // assuming bytes are separated by non-numeric characters
    // and never overflow
    char ch = Serial.read();
    if ( (ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9') ) {
        strIntensity[idxChar++] = ch;
    } else {
        strIntensity[idxChar] = 0;
        sensorReading = atoi(strIntensity);
        idxChar = 0;
    }
    if (idxChar>=BUFFER_SIZE-1) {
        // (need space for the null char at the end too
        // Buffer overflow.  Bail 
        idxChar = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not actually sending in the intensity. The LEDs are just being turned on/off based on the value of the sensorReading parameter. My confusion is why both methods light up LEDs based on sensorReading they have different intensities. I am adding full code to question.

Comment: No loop in the Processing code. But I am looping constantly in the Arduino code (of course). Would dropping the baud rate help with this?

Comment: That was it! I added a delay in the Arduino code and it is looking good: `delay(17);`

Comment: @wergeld Revised the answer again with my personal recommendation. Cheers!

Comment: I moved your example code from Processing to Arduino code file (modded of course). Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

> // read the most recent byte (which will be from 0 to 1023)

Bytes go from 0 to 255.  And they (usually) represent characters from the ASCII character set.

If you are expecting to read numbers between 0 and 1023 they could be being transmitted a character at a time (ie a character `1` followed by a character `0` would represent the number 10) - in which case you have to parse them to turn them into a number that can be used as you expect.

The [parseInt](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StreamParseInt) function is probably what you need - [a tutorial on reading ASCII integers can be found here](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ReadASCIIString)

Comment: I changed the values expected in the arduino code to be 255. Still same issue.

Comment: Okay, I see what needs to be done but not how to do this. The `parseInt` requires a new stream class reference and a list of the stream to read. What would this code look like for the new stream class?

Comment: Serial is such a Stream, so you can just call Serial.parseInt() (as I understand it) - answer updated with a link to tutorial also.